# Controlling the width of elements in a Listview - flutter

Tags: listview, flutter

I have created a list view , containging 3 TextFields , the problem is that ofc , they expand through the all screen width.

I tried , wrapping them with a container and set a width , 
and wrap it with a LimitedBox and set maxWidth - Neither of them works
How i can control the width of the Textfields the inside the Listview , 
or please an alternative way to accomplish it.
I have added one of the Textfields with my tries of resizing its width
Thanks

```
ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            LimitedBox(
              maxWidth: 50,
              child: Container(
                width: 50,
                child: TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'you@example.com',
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                      labelText: 'E-mail adress',
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

),

Comment: use ***Sizedbox*** not ***LimitedBox*** , ***LimitedBox*** do no enforce all the time , or maybe use a  ***Row*** ☺ if you need more help , tag me

Answer (score 5):

use Row Widget

```
ListView(children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              LimitedBox(
                maxWidth: 50,
                child: Container(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'you@example.com',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, color: Colors.white),
                        labelText: 'E-mail adress',
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        )),
                  ),color: Colors.amber,
                ),
              )
          ],
        ),
        ])
```

[image]